# My Array merge sorter does not work properly with odd number length of the array that includes some duplicate values

Tags: java, arrays, mergesort

My Array merge sorter does not work properly with odd number length of the array that includes some duplicate values. For example, for `int[] array = {1, 3, 15, 3, 7, 9, 8, 15, 0}` the result is `{0, 1, 3, 3, 7, 8, 0, 9, 15,}`. Can someone tell me where I am wrong?

```
public static void mergeSort(int[] inputArray) {
    int size = inputArray.length;
    if (size < 2)
        return;
    int mid = size / 2;
    int leftSize = mid;
    int[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(inputArray, 0, leftSize);
    int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(inputArray, leftSize, inputArray.length);
    mergeSort(left);
    mergeSort(right);
    merge(left, right, inputArray);
}

public static void merge(int[] left, int[] right, int[] arr) {
    int leftSize = left.length;
    int rightSize = right.length;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < leftSize && j < rightSize) {
        if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
            arr[k++] = left[i++];
        } else {
            arr[k++] = right[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < leftSize) {
        arr[k++] = left[i++];
    }
    while (j < leftSize) {
        arr[k++] = right[j++];
    }
}
```

Comment: Small language fixes, add inline code blocks, tweak indentation of code blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this

```
while (j < leftSize) {
   arr[k++] = right[j++];
}
```

To

```
while (j < rightSize) {
   arr[k++] = right[j++];
}
```